# ZbarSDK errors (Screenshot included)

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, barcode-scanner

I keep getting errors trying to implement the ZBarSDK. I have previously done so without any problem but now it's making me go nuts :)
[image]

Anyone with any clue of what is going on, is welcome to answer..

Thanks in advance,

Lewion

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all of the required `Frameworks` are added to your Project.

[image]